# How to extract the file data and send the data to the form and fill the details automatically in python?

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu operating system, How to extract the file data and send the file data to the form and fill the details automatically in python?.

Let take a simple example. In resume.doc, my name, the phone number and the educational details etc. These data I have to extract and send it to form and fill the details automatically.

Resume.doc
abc
0000000
xxxxxxxxxx

userform.html (automatically fill the text fields by extratcing the data from Resume.doc)

name: abc
Phonenumber: 0000000
Education details: xxxxxxxxxx

Your help is really appreciable..Thanks for advance!!

Comment: Let's see some simple code ...

Comment: So you want to read information from a Word file and use it to fill in the fields of a web form?  Does the information have to come from a Word document, or could it be stored in a simple text file instead?

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @lxop : word doc or odt format but not a plain text file

Comment: @lxop: I am successfully extracting from one .doc format file data in to another .doc format file but I didn't understand how to send this data to the form  and fill the details automatically in python?.

Comment: @kjtl: Where is the sample code ?

Comment: @user2189870 Normally you show what you've tried. Maybe indicate what research you've done and always show where you're stuck ... currently you're asking people to write code for you.

Comment: @user2189870 see http://stackoverflow.com/faq